# Where "mUiThread" is assigned to reference UI thread in the class Activity.java?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

I've seen people referencing the following block of codes from android app
 Activity.java many times. My confusion here is that it doesn't make sense to me that "if(Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread)" is checking if the current thread is the UI thread, since I coudn't find anywhere in the Activity.java that 
"mUiThread" is the referecne of UI thread. There are three locations where 
"mUiThread" appears in Activity.java, including the one in the following codes, 
the other two locations are :

1) Line 926:  private Thread  mUiThread;

2) Line 7746:  mUiThread = Thread.currentThread();(Note: 
   this line is after the following codes,also it 
   follows the comment line //------ Internal API ------)

My question is: where "mUiThread" is assigned to reference UI thread in the class Activity.java https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java?

```
         public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
                if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
                    mHandler.post(action);
                } else {
                    action.run();
                }
            }
```

Comment: 2) is called within `final void attach(...)` which is called by the framework on ui thread and assigned there.

Comment: Thanks, Pawel, is this line "attachBaseContext(context);" attaching the Ui thread to the parameter context in  final void attach(...), and then doing the assignment by "mUiThread = Thread.currentThread()"?